# Eclipse moving code to src package

Tags: java, eclipse, package

A couple of days ago I decided to switch back to Eclipse from IntelliJ (did not touch any of this code with IntelliJ)

A few minutes ago I closed out of Eclipse, then reopened it to find that it has completely ruined my folder/package structure.
Instead of my packages being `me.moltenheim.game` it changed to `src.me.moltenheim.game`, I did not have a commit or anything so I pretty much lost around half an hours worth of work to eclipse being stupid.

This is what my package explorer looks like:
[image: Screenshot of package explorer]

Comment: Do you have `src` as a "source" directory in your project settings?

Comment: You probably need to configure the `Source` folders in the `Java Build Path` properties for the project.

Comment: Short answer: Yep. (Thanks minimum character limit)

Comment: @Moltenheim use `@<username>` in your comment so the corresponding people is notified about your answer to their comment (and you won't have problem with the minimum character limit ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, thanks to people in the comments.
All I had to do was go to the Project properties (`⌘I`, not sure about Windows & Linux) then `Java Build Path` removed the src folder in the Source tab and just selected it from add Folder.

[image: Solution]